# Import not being recognized within class

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

```
---src
   |___app
       |___add-property
           |___add-property.component.ts (where error is found)
       |___services
           |___add-property.service.ts
   app-routing.ts
```

(file tree added for reference)

```
import { Property } from '../models/Property';
import { AddPropertyService } from '../services/addProperty.service';
import { Routing } from '../app-routing';

export class AddPropertyComponent implements OnInit {

  private newProperty :Property;
  *** private routing :Routing; *** issue is right here

  constructor(private addPropertyService: AddPropertyService) { }
  this.routing.doSomething();
}
```

My goal is to have this.routing.doSomething get called at the bottom of this code block.  The portion of the code I have highlighted where the issue is located -- the error is

```
Cannot find name 'Routing'.
```

I also have Routing being exported from the file (where my routes are located).

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/properties', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
export const Routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

Does anyone know why it cannot find the name 'Routing', even though I believe I am doing everything correctly?

******* I SOLVED, ANSWER BELOW FOR FUTURE REFERENCE *******

I followed the Angular 'Routing' doc:

```
1. I created a app-routing.module.ts and deleted my app-routing.ts
2. Export AppRoutingModule within app-routing.module.ts
3. Import AppRoutingModule into component that was in need of routing (add-
   property.component.ts in my question)
4. Also Import Router module from '@angular/router'
5. Inside component constructor --> add private router: Router
6. this.router.navigate() is now available for use
```

Comment: What is the project file tree look like?

Comment: edit your question and properly tell me your project tree...

Comment: added file tree above.  let me know if more is needed.

Comment: In your tree what does the `--` mean? I'm confused as to whether the routing ts lives in `service` or not.

Comment: app-routing is not within a folder.  I added the services folder for obscure reference (the file is Imported in the code above)

Comment: I think your problem is the line `const Routing` you never declared it's type. you have a variable named `Routing` and you probably mean `const routes: Routing`?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not initializing the Routing service in the constructor and calling the `doSomething` in `ngOnInit()`?

Comment: I actually tried that and was seeing the same "Cannot find name 'Routing'" error (in the constructor arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

`import { Routing } from '../app-routing';`

Should be:

`import { Routing } from '../../../app-routing';`

**Update**

It seems that the path is in the right place (see comments).

Well the other thing that could be is that you are using `Routing` as a `Type`.
If you want to use it as a `Type` it should be of type `ModuleWithProviders`.

Try with this:

```
private routing = Routing;
```

Also this should work too:

```
private routing: ModuleWithProviders = Routing;
```

Documentation:

- [forRoot](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule)
- [ModuleWithProviders](https://angular.io/api/core/ModuleWithProviders)

If you want to have your `doSomething()` function you will need to change your export to something else like:

`export const ROUTING = { 
    routing: RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES),
    doSomething: () => {
       // just do something
    }
}`

It's a better practice to use a `class` or an `interface` to hold these values, you want to have all typed, that is the price of typescript if you don't follow that principle, you will end with `any` declarations everywhere.

Comment: thanks for answering, but the path is correct.  The path above may be slightly misleading - wasn't entirely how best to display it.

Comment: (newbie with Angular so appreciate the help) The this.routing.doSomething() seen above is now throwing the error --> Property 'doSomething' does not exist on type 'ModuleWithProviders'.  Any idea why this is?

Comment: I have updated my answer to cover that, I hope it helps, remember to mark the answer as the solution if it solves your question.